# withTrashed() doesn't work on server

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, soft-delete

I'm using soft deletes for my models, and in some cases I'm querying deleted models via relations like this

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

The problem is that on my local env (laravel homestead) everything is fine but this relation returns null on hosting.

When I try to debug SQL queries local version looks like this

```
select * from `teams` where `teams`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Server version looks like this

```
select * 
from `teams` 
where `teams`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
  and `teams`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: What is "hosting"? Make sure the code on the server is actually what you think it is. Do you have a different config file?

Comment: "hosting" is a dev server on https://hostinguk.net/, code is the same on local and hosting. Think that config is not an issue as i actually have different db queries

Comment: In which case, you need to talk to your hosting provider. Without knowing what is different between your local environment and your hosted enviornment, it's impossible for anyone to replicate the issue or provide a solution.

Comment: yep there's different file versions on local and server - thanks dude

Comment: Great. Consider deleting your question =]

Answer (score 0):

Check that your model has exactly

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

and whithin your class

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

I had a similar problem and the error was a lowercase